# Avoiding nested transactions with optional parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two functions Method1() and Method2(). Each one of these methods is inside a transaction

```
public void Method1() {
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
       // Do Stuff
       scope.Complete()
    }
}

public void Method2() {
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
       // Do Stuff 2
       scope.Complete()
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to make a new method that combines method1 and 2 and has to be atomic too.

```
 public void Method1and2() {
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
        Method1();
        Method2();
        scope.Complete()
    }
 }
```

I want it to be all or nothing. As I can see it,

I have two options:
   1. Duplicate Method1() and Method2() without the Transaction (method overload) in this way:

```
public void Method1() {
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
       // Do Stuff
       scope.Complete()
    }
}

public void Method1(bool anything ) {
       // Do Stuff
}
```

Or I use an optional parameter in Method1 and Method2:

```
public void Method1(bool ignoreTransaction = false) {
        var typeTransaction = TransactionScopeOption.Required;

        if (ignoreTransaction)
            typeTransaction = TransactionScopeOption.Suppress;

    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(typeTransaction)) {
       // Do Stuff
       scope.Complete()
    }
}
```

Which one would be better?

Comment: Why not just `public void Method1(TransactionScopeOption option = TransactionScopeOption.Required)` instead of using `boolean`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood TransactionScopeOption.Supress. It will remove the block from all transactions?

`Voting inside a nested scope

Although a nested scope can join the ambient transaction of the root scope, calling Complete in the nested scope has no affect on the root scope. Only if all the scopes from the root scope down to the last nested scope vote to commit the transaction, will the transaction be committed. Not calling Complete in a nested scope will affect the root scope as the ambient transaction will immediately be aborted.`